# Update user claims without updating authentication time

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity, httpcontext

I've seen many posts about updating user claims but finally they all use `SignIn` method which updates **authentication time**. There is a core functionality in my web application based on authentication time.

Is there any solution to leave authentication time as is and update/add claims?

Comment: Are you using `asp.net mvc` or `asp.net core` or `asp.net core mvc` ?

Comment: I'm using asp.net core mvc

Comment: No. Claims are included in the token. That's why a user must essentially be logged out and back in to refresh claims: they're being given a new token.